# Sorry, we have no imagery here - Google Satellite Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Satellite map on an application. It was working fine and suddenly the map images start not showing. Instead of the terrain images, the map is showing the message "*Sorry, we have no imagery here*".

It is happening on my office IP and other testers' IPs. If I access from another IP or mobile data it works and shown the satellite images. I am not sure if google blocks IPs in case of continuous access on the maps.

[image]

Also I am able to see a lot of errors accessing the images

[image]

While clicking on the links for loading images, I am getting an error page like below instead of the map tile image.

[image]

Any clues on this issue is appreciated

Comment: Where does that happen? What coordinates? What zoom level?

Comment: It happens on all places, and zoom level is set to 11, but it happens on all zoom levels.

Comment: You are likely triggered automatic blocking from the Google anti-abuse system. In order to unblock your IP you should contact Google support via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all the response and I was able to find and fix the real issue. Adding the details here for reference.

I have contacted Google support with the request details and they were able to figure out the exact problem. The reason is their image servers are blocking the request from this project (hybrid mobile project - Android) since it found out that there are invalid request is also coming from the project. The invalid request is referred to as the requests without proper header information.

Based on that information, I could find out that a caching mechanism in the project was trying to cache the images and that is which sends the invalid requests. Adding proper header to that cache mechanism solved the issue forever.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid showing these errors, in case they are due to the use of a zoom level that is too high for the area you are viewing, you can use the [`MaxZoomService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom).

```js
var map, maxZoomService;

function initialize() {

  maxZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {

    checkZoom();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    checkZoom();
  });
}

function checkZoom() {

  let zoom = map.getZoom();

  maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(map.getCenter(), function(response) {
  
    if (response.status !== 'OK') {
    
      alert('maxZoomService error: ' + response.status);
      document.getElementById('max-zoom').innerHTML = 'n/a';
      document.getElementById('max-zoom-service').innerHTML = response.status;
      
    } else {

      if (response.zoom < zoom) {

        map.setZoom(response.zoom);
        
        document.getElementById('max-zoom').innerHTML = response.zoom;
        document.getElementById('max-zoom-service').innerHTML = response.status;
      }
    }
    
    document.getElementById('curr-zoom').innerHTML = map.getZoom();
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 130px;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
Current Zoom Level: <span id="curr-zoom"></span><br>
Max Zoom Level: <span id="max-zoom"></span><br>
Max Zoom Service Status: <span id="max-zoom-service"></span>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

If the zoom level is not the issue, make sure that you are using a valid API key. In any case, it might be worth creating a new key and trying again with that one. If that still doesn't work, I would try to contact Google directly with more information as it might be that your network IP or IP range was banned by Google for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried your code but I still have the issue. Seems like it is not the issue with the zoom level.

Comment: Then check your key (are you using a valid key?) and if that isn't the issue, then try contacting Google directly.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but, I recently got this error too. So, the problem, in my case was the version of the API script I was using.

I'm answering this because I didn't found this solution over here, so, just in case someone was getting the same error.

Just adding v=3.35 (version number) to the url and it works.

Example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.35&key=API_KEY...

They explain here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#an-update-affected-my-application

Comment: This "we have no imagery here" issue that happened last Jul 26, 2019 has already been fixed. This was also reported in Google's Public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138408915

The issue was due to the recent Maps JavaScript API version 3.37 rollover which was already fixed by Google engineers as per the public bug. If the error with the new version is still reproducible on your end, you can comment on the issue link above for the engineers to further investigate.